# .jif images do not show thumbnail on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, jpeg, thumbnails

Any JPG, GIF, PNG, etc, will display a Thumbnail on Windows File Explorer.

However, JIF images don't:

[image]

If I rename ".jif" to ".jpg", it displays the thumbnail:

[image]

Is there any way to make Windows see ".jif" as ".jpg", so that thumbnails are always shown?

I believe 100% of the ".jif" files I have saved came from downloads on Chrome/Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way to make windows 10 show thumbnails for JIF images but if you change a value in the windows Registry you can get Chrome/Firefox to save images as jpeg instead of jif.

Open Registry Editor, then go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\image/jpg
Right click on Extension go to modify and change .jif to .jpg
Now images from Firefox should download as jpg
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUkvi.png